# Как выставить текст на блоке flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Друзья, всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста. Есть макет, я верстаю на  flex-боксах. Как можно сделать текст на блоке формы? Flex не дает растянуть ее наверх.

HTML

```
<div class="header-form">
                 <h1>Заборы, калитки, ворота<br>
                 «ПОД КЛЮЧ»</h1>
                  <form action="#" class="form-offer">
                   <input type="name" placeholder="Ваше имя">
                   <input type="tel" placeholder="+375(  )___-___-___">
                   <input type="submit" value ="Связаться">
                   </form>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
.header-form{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;

}

.header-form h1{
    font-size:230%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color:#ffffff;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;


}
.form-offer{
    flex-basis:100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #4d5665;
    padding: 7% 7% 4% 7%;
    justify-content: flex-end;



}
.form-offer input{
    margin-bottom:5%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 70%;
    padding:10px;

}
.form-offer input[type="submit"]{
    background-color: #d5b58e;
    border: 1px solid #d5b58e;
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: 12%;

}
```

Comment: Вы можете форме дать отрицательный margin-top и поднять ее на нужную величину.

Comment: @Alex если даю margin-top , то форма уменьшается соответственно вниз, потому что это flex-элементы

Answer (score 0):

Если с минимальными изменениями... Добавлено:

> .header-form { position: relative; ...
>   
>  .header-form h1 { position: absolute; top: 0;
>   
>  .form-offer { padding: 15% ...

(и прямо в здешней песочнице видно, почему padding % в этом случае - бобо), или можно и font-size, и padding привязать к `vh` например.

```css
.header-form{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.header-form h1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    font-size:230%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.form-offer{
    flex-basis:100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #4d5665;
    padding: 15% 7% 4% 7%;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
.form-offer input{
    margin-bottom:5%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 70%;
    padding:10px;
}
.form-offer input[type="submit"]{
    background-color: #d5b58e;
    border: 1px solid #d5b58e;
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: 12%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-form">
  <h1>Заборы, калитки, ворота<br>
    «ПОД КЛЮЧ»</h1>
  <form action="#" class="form-offer">
    <input type="name" placeholder="Ваше имя">
    <input type="tel" placeholder="+375(  )___-___-___">
    <input type="submit" value ="Связаться">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я так пробовал и получается почему-то вот так: https://imgur.com/RK6rr1p